# Build Failing - Missing Visual studio 2017 data tool

Tags: build, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am getting below error while building my project. It seems I am missing data tool components on my build agent

> No agent found in pool Hosted VS2017 which satisfies the specified
>   demands: sqlpackage Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.103.0

But I am unable to get offline installer for data tools for VS 2017. Please help.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The sqlpackage.exe is existing on Hosted VS 2017 agent, but not in the capacity list. (can’t add this capacity manually and use deploy database task, check [VS2017 Hosted Agent: SQL Server Data Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4338))

The workaround is that you can call sqlpackage.exe command by using Command Line task:

1. Right click your project > Publish to create a publish profile
2. Edit that publish profile to add **Password** to TargetConnectionString (Could be tokenized by using [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens))

Sample:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=XXX.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True</TargetConnectionString>
```

3. Check in changes
4. Add Command line task: (Tool: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\sqlpackage.exe`; Arguments: `/Action:Publish /SourceFile:"$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\DatabaseDemo.dacpac" /Profile:"$(build.sourcesdirectory)\DatabaseDemo\DatabaseDemo.publish.xml"`)
5. Queue build with Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: Is there any updates on this? I have SSDT 2017 installed on a build server as a private agent. SQLPackage.exe is not added as a capability even though SSDT 2017 is installed. I tried manually adding the sqlpackage.exe location to the PATH system environment variables and that did not help either. Installing SSDT 2015 adds the SQLPackage.exe as a capability, but not SSDT 2017.  The above proposed solution does not help as you need the sqlpackage capability for an Azure Database deploy task.